# Use LDAP Server to log into itself

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have an LDAP server (running 18.04LTS) and a bunch of Linux Ubuntu clients.  LDAP works fine and we're just using it to authenticate a couple users.

My question is as follows.  I'd like to use the same LDAP database to log into the LDAP server itself!  (not using local IDs).

Do I just install the LDAP client utils? I'm worried they'll blow away the server config.  Don't tell me it's that easy?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same PAM/NSS service querying the LDAP server like on your other systems.

You might want to have some emergency login available if your LDAP service is not up and running.